# How to set hidden label and value with AddressBook Framework in cocoa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, abaddressbook

I know how to add a label&value into a local contact,just like this:
    CFErrorRef error;

```
ABMultiValueRef ref = ABRecordCopyValue(self.record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
ABMutableMultiValueRef copyOfRef = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(ref);

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(copyOfRef, (CFStringRef)account, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(self.record, kABPersonPhoneProperty, copyOfRef, &error);

ECP4iPhoneAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ECP4iPhoneAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ABAddressBookSave([appDelegate.gLABAddressBook addressBook], &error);

CFRelease(copyOfRef);
CFRelease(ref);
```

But how could I add a **hidden label** and value into a local contact?Because I wanna use some properties in my own app,thx

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You should create a data structure that solves that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is impossible as far as I know